# move clip to next empty channel script

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor

I have 10 to 20 movie clips on a single channel in the VSE.

1) Is there a way to distribute each clip to its own individual empty channel?

2) Keep the clips start point and extend the end points to the end point of the last clip? maybe with:

```
py.ops.sequencer.select_handles(side='RIGHT')
bpy.ops.sequencer.snap(frame=something)
```

is it possible to automate this process with a scrip? any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Remember that Blender's VSE doesn't have unlimited number of tracks or channels. IIRC its 32

Comment: There will only be 10 or so. I plan to make a metta strip with the moved strips once they are moved and extended.

Comment: This is fascinating, what do you use the long tails for? Are you compositing a bunch of smaller screens together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a test script.  All strips on channel 1 are selected, sorted by frame_start,  then added to channels 2, 3, 4 etc.  and extended to the frame_final_end of each to the frame_final_end of the last strip.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
se = scene.sequence_editor

strips = [s for s in se.sequences_all if s.channel == 1]
strips.sort(key=lambda x:x.frame_start)
print(strips)
end_point_of_last_clip = strips[-1].frame_final_end
for i, s in enumerate(strips):
    s.channel += i
    s.frame_final_end = end_point_of_last_clip
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, it does exactly what I wanted. I'll learn loads from this!